# Ngx translate using environment to get Assets

Tags: javascript, angular

I've already used ngx in another application and it was pretty cool.
However in this application instead of getting in the default location localhost:4200/assets it keeps trying to get in the environment localhost:8080.
I don't know why this is happening. In the other application it is also being using the environment

```js
/*environment*/

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
};


/* APP MODULE */

export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
    })
```

````css
/*home component*/

ngOnInit() {
  this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  this.translate.use('en');
}

```
auth.service

  {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true,
},

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
// Clone the request to add the new authenticated header.
const authReq = req.clone({
  url: environment.baseUrl + req.url,
  headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', SessionService.getToken())
});

// Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
return next.handle(authReq)
  .pipe(
    tap(event => {}, err => {
      // If unauthorized request
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403)) {
        this.loginService.logout();
      }
    })
  );
  }
```
````

localhost:8080 and does the get in the normal localhost:4200.
Could you help me with this?

Comment: Check this post:
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/853

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work, please include your `angular.json` file content in your question.

Comment: @AmerYousuf I added angular.json, the code below didn't work

Comment: Where do you store the translation file? Are they under the `assets/i18n/` folder, one JSON file for each language or not?

Comment: Also, check if the link mentioned by @Guiditox if will resolve your issue or not.

Comment: I found the problem,
is the auth interceptor, if i comment it ngx works. But I don't know a method so that when the request is from ngx it doesn't go through the auth service

Comment: I put the auth code above so you can see  @AmerYousuf

Comment: Check my answer now, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following in your `HttpLoaderFactory`:

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

In case you're using an `interceptor` (e.g. `AuthInterceptor`), you should force it to handle the requests start with `baseUrl` only, and ignore the local ones, like the following:

```js
intercept(
  request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (request.url.startsWith(environment.baseUrl)) {
    // Add your logic here
    // e.g. inject the token and next.handle the request again
  } else {
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```